# My Vscode does not supporting xsl version 2.0, that's why it it giving me unwanted xml tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

```
**Not getting the desired xml output using XSLT in VSCODE, But XSL code running perfectly in online XML-XSLT Compiler.** 
**Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations (XSLT) is an XML-based language used, in conjunction with specialized processing software, for the transformation of XML documents.Then, the new document may be serialized (output) by the processor in standard XML syntax or in another format, such as HTML or plain text.**
**XSLT 2.0 is a revised version of the XSLT 1.0 Recommendation [XSLT 1.0] published on 16 November 1999.
```

XSLT 2.0 is designed to be used in conjunction with XPath 2.0, which is defined in [XPath 2.0]. XSLT shares the same data model as XPath 2.0, which is defined in [Data Model], and it uses the library of functions and operators defined in [Functions and Operators].
XSLT 2.0 also includes optional facilities to serialize the results of a transformation, by means of an interface to the serialization component described in [XSLT and XQuery Serialization].
This document contains hyperlinks to specific sections or definitions within other documents in this family of specifications. These links are indicated visually by a superscript identifying the target specification: for example XP for XPath, DM for the XDM data model, FO for Functions and Operators.**

```
Here, the XSL which we designed:
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/document">
        <document>
            <xsl:for-each select="page">
                <page>
                     <xsl:for-each select="block">
                      
                            <xsl:if test = "@blockType='Text'">
                                <block blockType="{@blockType}">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="text">
                                            <text>
                                                <xsl:for-each select="par">
                                                    <paragraph>
                                                        <line>
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="line"/>
                                                        </line>
                                                    </paragraph>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                            </text>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                </block>
                            </xsl:if>  
                            
                            <xsl:if test = "@blockType='Table'">
                                <block blockType="{@blockType}">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="row">
                                        <row>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="cell">
                                                <cell>
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="text">  
                                                    <text>
                                                        <xsl:for-each select="par">
                                                        <paragraph>
                                                            <line>
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="line"/>
                                                            </line>
                                                        </paragraph>
                                                        </xsl:for-each>  
                                                    </text>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>  
                                                </cell>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </row>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </block>
                            </xsl:if>                              
                    </xsl:for-each>    
                </page>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </document>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
    
    
    Here, the Input XML which we want to transform:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <document xmlns="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml" version="1.0" producer="ABBYY FineReader Engine 12" pagesCount="2" languages="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml">
    <page width="2550" height="3300" resolution="300" originalCoords="1">
    <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="1879" t="150" r="2378" b="193"><region><rect l="1879" t="150" r="2378" b="193"/></region>
    <text>
    <par lineSpacing="1150">
    <line baseline="186" l="1885" t="156" r="2372" b="187"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">ABBYY FineReader OCR</formatting></line></par>
    </text>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="354" t="295" r="1002" b="363"><region><rect l="354" t="295" r="1002" b="363"/></region>
    <text>
    <par lineSpacing="1610">
    <line baseline="346" l="360" t="301" r="996" b="357"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Digital Camera OCR</formatting></line></par>
    </text>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="349" t="384" r="2376" b="483"><region><rect l="349" t="384" r="2376" b="483"/></region>
    <text>
    <par lineSpacing="1150">
    <line baseline="421" l="358" t="390" r="2365" b="430"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Using Digital Camera to Capture Text.1</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1150">
    <line baseline="469" l="355" t="438" r="2370" b="477"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Tips &amp; Tricks for Shooting Text with Digital Camera.2</formatting></line></par>
    </text>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="349" t="545" r="2001" b="610"><region><rect l="349" t="545" r="2001" b="610"/></region>
    <text>
    <par lineSpacing="1610">
    <line baseline="592" l="355" t="551" r="1995" b="604"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Alternative Way to Digitize and Repurpose Documents and Books</formatting></line></par>
    </text>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="350" t="664" r="2349" b="1311"><region><rect l="1031" t="664" r="2349" b="1165"/><rect l="350" t="1165" r="2349" b="1311"/></region>
    <text>
    <par lineSpacing="1160">
    <line baseline="701" l="1040" t="670" r="2343" b="709"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Have you ever think that your digital camera could successfully replace</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="748" l="1038" t="718" r="2336" b="757"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">a scanner for document processing with OCR? Have you ever suspect</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="797" l="1037" t="766" r="2274" b="805"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">that your digital camera could capture text which normally would be</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="845" l="1039" t="813" r="1285" b="845"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">inaccessible?</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="950" l="1037" t="919" r="2209" b="959"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">With new ABBYY FineReader OCR and its adaptive recognition</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="999" l="1037" t="958" r="2191" b="1007"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">technology1 for camera images, it’s really time to think about it!</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="1105" l="1040" t="1074" r="2203" b="1113"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Digital cameras are becoming more and more popular and truly</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="1153" l="1039" t="1122" r="2318" b="1161"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">multipurpose. In addition to everything else, you can use your camera</formatting></line></par>
    </text>
    <text>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="1201" l="356" t="1170" r="2233" b="1209"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">as a portable “scanner” to capture text from hardcopy documents, books, newspapers, as well as from</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="1248" l="357" t="1217" r="2236" b="1257"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">banners, posters and other media. Then, with ABBYY FineReader OCR, you can convert your camera</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="1297" l="357" t="1265" r="2220" b="1305"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">images into electronic text files for editing, archiving, creating new documents and for other purposes.</formatting></line></par>
    </text>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Picture" blockName="" l="351" t="683" r="999" b="1146"><region><rect l="351" t="683" r="999" b="1146"/></region>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="349" t="1373" r="2369" b="2188"><region><rect l="349" t="1373" r="2369" b="2188"/></region>
    <text>
    <par lineSpacing="1610">
    <line baseline="1419" l="356" t="1379" r="1308" b="1431"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Using Digital Camera to Capture Text</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="1528" l="355" t="1497" r="2339" b="1537"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">A digital camera is an ideal alternative to a scanner, if you don’t want to deal with a scanner each time when</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="1576" l="356" t="1545" r="2363" b="1584"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">you need to convert a document into a text file, especially if you don’t do it very often. Camera images can be</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="1624" l="356" t="1593" r="1548" b="1632"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">easily opened in ABBYY FineReader OCR, ready for processing.</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="1730" l="357" t="1699" r="2229" b="1739"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">If you are working with books (for example, in a library), you can simply take you digital camera and</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="1778" l="356" t="1747" r="2342" b="1787"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">capture all necessary text and images for further processing on you PC or notebook (even from those books</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="1826" l="355" t="1795" r="909" b="1834"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">that cannot be scanned at all).</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="1932" l="366" t="1901" r="2240" b="1941"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">When you are traveling out of the office (for example, on a business trip) and need to digitize some</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="1980" l="357" t="1949" r="2231" b="1989"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">important documents for editing, archiving, creating other documents, digital camera can be used as a</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="2028" l="357" t="1998" r="673" b="2036"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">portable scanner.</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="2135" l="355" t="2103" r="2212" b="2143"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">A digital camera can also be used to capture text outdoors from banners, posters, billboards, walls,</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="2182" l="355" t="2152" r="747" b="2182"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">timetables and so on.</formatting></line></par>
    </text>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="349" t="2251" r="2372" b="2351"><region><rect l="349" t="2251" r="2372" b="2351"/></region>
    <text>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="2289" l="355" t="2257" r="2284" b="2297"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">At last, you will probably find your own way to use a digital camera and its new capabilities. But if you are</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="2337" l="356" t="2305" r="2366" b="2345"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">going to use it like James Bond does, please don’t forget about intellectual property rights and copyright laws.</formatting></line></par>
    </text>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="356" t="3011" r="1307" b="3061"><region><rect l="356" t="3011" r="1307" b="3061"/></region>
    <text>
    <par lineSpacing="1090">
    <line baseline="3054" l="362" t="3017" r="1301" b="3055"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">1 More information is available at www.FineReader.com</formatting></line></par>
    </text>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="1351" t="3102" r="1376" b="3147"><region><rect l="1351" t="3102" r="1376" b="3147"/></region>
    <text>
    <par lineSpacing="1380">
    <line baseline="3141" l="1357" t="3108" r="1370" b="3141"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">1</formatting></line></par>
    </text>
    </block>
    <block blockType="SeparatorsBox" blockName="" l="351" t="683" r="999" b="1146"><region><rect l="351" t="683" r="999" b="687"/><rect l="351" t="687" r="999" b="1142"/><rect l="351" t="1142" r="999" b="1146"/></region>
    <separatorsBox>
    <separator type="Black" thickness="4"><start x="351" y="685"/><end x="999" y="685"/>
    </separator>
    <separator type="Black" thickness="4"><start x="351" y="1144"/><end x="999" y="1144"/>
    </separator>
    <separator type="Black" thickness="4"><start x="353" y="683"/><end x="353" y="1146"/>
    </separator>
    <separator type="Black" thickness="3"><start x="997" y="683"/><end x="997" y="1146"/>
    </separator>
    </separatorsBox>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Separator" blockName="" l="539" t="742" r="821" b="750"><region><rect l="539" t="742" r="821" b="749"/><rect l="539" t="749" r="821" b="750"/></region>
    <separator type="Black" thickness="7"><start x="539" y="746"/><end x="821" y="746"/>
    </separator>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Separator" blockName="" l="600" t="944" r="814" b="949"><region><rect l="600" t="944" r="608" b="945"/><rect l="600" t="945" r="778" b="947"/><rect l="600" t="947" r="814" b="949"/></region>
    <separator type="Black" thickness="3"><start x="600" y="946"/><end x="814" y="946"/>
    </separator>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Separator" blockName="" l="355" t="2991" r="954" b="2994"><region><rect l="355" t="2991" r="954" b="2994"/></region>
    <separator type="Black" thickness="3"><start x="355" y="2992"/><end x="954" y="2992"/>
    </separator>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Separator" blockName="" l="511" t="896" r="514" b="984"><region><rect l="511" t="896" r="514" b="984"/></region>
    <separator type="Black" thickness="3"><start x="512" y="896"/><end x="512" y="984"/>
    </separator>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Separator" blockName="" l="842" t="846" r="846" b="989"><region><rect l="843" t="846" r="846" b="980"/><rect l="842" t="980" r="846" b="989"/></region>
    <separator type="Black" thickness="3"><start x="844" y="846"/><end x="844" y="989"/>
    </separator>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Separator" blockName="" l="1062" t="416" r="2344" b="421"><region><rect l="1062" t="416" r="2344" b="421"/></region>
    <separator type="Dotted" thickness="5"><start x="1062" y="418"/><end x="2344" y="418"/>
    </separator>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Separator" blockName="" l="1303" t="464" r="2344" b="469"><region><rect l="1303" t="464" r="2344" b="469"/></region>
    <separator type="Dotted" thickness="5"><start x="1303" y="466"/><end x="2344" y="466"/>
    </separator>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Picture" blockName="" l="509" t="713" r="849" b="985"><region><rect l="509" t="713" r="849" b="985"/></region>
    </block>
    </page>
    <page width="2550" height="3300" resolution="300" originalCoords="1">
    <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="1803" t="70" r="2302" b="113"><region><rect l="1803" t="70" r="2302" b="113"/></region>
    <text>
    <par lineSpacing="1150">
    <line baseline="106" l="1809" t="76" r="2296" b="107"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">ABBYY FineReader OCR</formatting></line></par>
    </text>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="273" t="165" r="2259" b="1589"><region><rect l="273" t="165" r="2259" b="1323"/><rect l="727" t="1323" r="2259" b="1589"/></region>
    <text>
    <par lineSpacing="1610">
    <line baseline="212" l="281" t="171" r="1601" b="224"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Tips &amp; Tricks for Shooting Text with Digital Camera</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="321" l="282" t="290" r="2149" b="329"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">It is important to learn how to use a digital camera effectively for the best OCR results, even for skillful</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="369" l="281" t="337" r="2142" b="377"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">photographers. Camera images differ from scanned images by a range of characteristics, but ABBYY</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="417" l="282" t="385" r="2238" b="425"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">FineReader OCR, with its adaptive recognition technology for camera images, makes them appropriate for</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="465" l="280" t="433" r="981" b="465"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">OCR and conversion into text formats.</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="537" l="281" t="506" r="2187" b="546"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">So, if you have FineReader OCR installed on your PC and know some simple “secrets” on how to shoot</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="585" l="280" t="554" r="1843" b="594"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">documents and books, you will certainly receive perfect results. Well, the secrets are:</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1260">
    <line baseline="662" l="279" t="629" r="745" b="670"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Your Digital Camera</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="734" l="282" t="703" r="2174" b="742"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Use a digital camera with 4-megapixel resolution or higher, ideally equipped with the following features:</formatting></line></par>
    <par startIndent="1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="785" l="355" t="754" r="788" b="785"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Flash disable mode</formatting></line></par>
    <par startIndent="1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="835" l="355" t="804" r="669" b="843"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Optical zoom</formatting></line></par>
    <par startIndent="1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="886" l="355" t="855" r="823" b="886"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• An anti-shake feature</formatting></line></par>
    <par startIndent="1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="936" l="355" t="905" r="1220" b="945"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Auto focus assist beam or manual focusing</formatting></line></par>
    <par startIndent="1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="987" l="355" t="957" r="1334" b="996"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Manual aperture control or aperture priority mode</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1260">
    <line baseline="1064" l="280" t="1031" r="570" b="1072"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">General Tips</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1128">
    <line baseline="1136" l="279" t="1105" r="2233" b="1144"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Try to take 2-3 shots of the same document to make sure your hands are stable and an image didn’t come</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="1184" l="280" t="1153" r="1238" b="1192"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">out blurry or a corner of the document wasn’t cut off.</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1128">
    <line baseline="1232" l="282" t="1201" r="1831" b="1240"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Use the “close-up” or “macro” mode. In most cameras it is indicated by a flower icon.</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1260">
    <line baseline="1308" l="280" t="1276" r="982" b="1316"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Camera Positioning and Focus</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="1383" l="733" t="1352" r="1805" b="1391"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Position the lens parallel to the plane of the document.</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="1434" l="733" t="1403" r="1507" b="1434"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Fit the entire document into the frame.</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="1485" l="733" t="1453" r="1368" b="1493"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Focus on the center of a page.</formatting></line></par>
    <par leftIndent="1800" startIndent="-1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="1535" l="733" t="1504" r="2253" b="1544"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Use the camera’s optical zoom to zoom in on the document and frame it tightly</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="1583" l="808" t="1553" r="1208" b="1583"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">around the document.</formatting></line></par>
    </text>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="273" t="1721" r="2281" b="2618"><region><rect l="273" t="1721" r="2281" b="2618"/></region>
    <text>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="1759" l="282" t="1727" r="706" b="1768"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Lighting and Flash</formatting></line></par>
    <par startIndent="1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="1810" l="355" t="1778" r="1546" b="1818"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Make sure there is sufficient lighting. Natural light is the best.</formatting></line></par>
    <par startIndent="1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="1860" l="355" t="1829" r="2192" b="1869"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Disable the flash (in most point-and-shoot digital cameras, the flash is on auto mode by default).</formatting></line></par>
    <par startIndent="1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="1911" l="355" t="1880" r="2214" b="1919"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• If you have to take a picture of a document in poor lighting and need the flash, try to use the flash</formatting></line></par>
    <par startIndent="3600" lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="1959" l="429" t="1928" r="1518" b="1967"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">from 20 inches away and try to find additional light sources.</formatting></line></par>
    <par startIndent="1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="2009" l="355" t="1978" r="1087" b="2018"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Don’t use the flash on glossy paper.</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="2086" l="282" t="2053" r="981" b="2094"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Extra Tips for Advanced Users</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="2133" l="279" t="2102" r="2275" b="2142"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">And finally, if you know your camera “inside out” and wish to improve your skills in photographing documents</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="2181" l="280" t="2150" r="2207" b="2189"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">and books or wish to achieve good results in some special conditions, there are a few extra tips to follow:</formatting></line></par>
    <par leftIndent="3600" startIndent="-1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="2232" l="355" t="2201" r="2275" b="2240"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Use the white balance feature. If your camera has manual white balance, use a white sheet of paper</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="2280" l="429" t="2249" r="2209" b="2288"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">to set white balance. Otherwise, select the appropriate balance mode for your lighting conditions.</formatting></line></par>
    <par startIndent="1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="2331" l="355" t="2300" r="1416" b="2339"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Enable the anti-shake setting: otherwise, use a tripod.</formatting></line></par>
    <par lineSpacing="1152">
    <line baseline="2403" l="282" t="2373" r="759" b="2412"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">In poor lighting conditions:</formatting></line></par>
    <par startIndent="1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="2454" l="355" t="2423" r="1930" b="2462"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Auto focus may function incorrectly: therefore, you should switch to manual focus.</formatting></line></par>
    <par leftIndent="3600" startIndent="-1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="2505" l="355" t="2474" r="2154" b="2513"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• Use the maximum aperture allowed by the camera (2.3 or 4.5). (In bright daylight, use smaller</formatting></line>
    <line baseline="2553" l="430" t="2522" r="1245" b="2561"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">apertures: this will produce sharper images).</formatting></line></par>
    <par startIndent="1800" lineSpacing="1152" isListItem="1" lstLvl="0">
    <line baseline="2603" l="355" t="2572" r="2121" b="2612"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">• If your camera gives you more than one choice of ISO speed, select the highest ISO setting.</formatting></line></par>
    </text>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Picture" blockName="" l="315" t="1349" r="697" b="1693"><region><rect l="315" t="1349" r="697" b="1693"/></region>
    </block>
    <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="1270" t="3021" r="1304" b="3067"><region><rect l="1270" t="3021" r="1304" b="3067"/></region>
    <text>
    <par lineSpacing="1380">
    <line baseline="3061" l="1276" t="3027" r="1297" b="3061"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">2</formatting></line></par>
    </text>
    </block>
    <block blockType="SeparatorsBox" blockName="" l="315" t="1349" r="697" b="1693"><region><rect l="315" t="1349" r="697" b="1352"/><rect l="315" t="1352" r="697" b="1689"/><rect l="315" t="1689" r="697" b="1693"/></region>
    <separatorsBox>
    <separator type="Black" thickness="3"><start x="315" y="1350"/><end x="697" y="1350"/>
    </separator>
    <separator type="Black" thickness="4"><start x="315" y="1691"/><end x="697" y="1691"/>
    </separator>
    <separator type="Black" thickness="4"><start x="317" y="1349"/><end x="317" y="1693"/>
    </separator>
    <separator type="Black" thickness="4"><start x="695" y="1349"/><end x="695" y="1693"/>
    </separator>
    </separatorsBox>
    </block>
    </page>
    </document>
    
    
    
    
    Here, the Output from online XSLT compiler: 
    (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiHX/30)
    
    
    But, in the transformed XML Output using XSLT in VSCODE we are getting the error.
    [enter image description here][1]
    
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iadXt.png
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The xslt which we have made, not working in the vscode. But, giving the correct output in online xml-xslt compiler.

Comment: Hi Michael, can you help with this..

Comment: To answer this question, we would need to know exactly how XSLT is being invoked from VS Code? VS Code has no built-in capability to run XSLT. An extension is being used, but which one? What XSLT processor is that extension invoking?